# WPF Binding - Lable binding problems

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I'm trying to use the `Async DataBinding`, this 'cause I need to execute several thread on my application that must be access to UI controls. For doing this I've declared a `Label` as:

```
<Label x:Name="SyncRange" Content="{Binding NextSynchronization, IsAsync=True}" />
```

(note that is my own control), so inside the class of the control I've defined this:

```
private string nextSync = "N/A";

public string NextSynchronization {
    get {
        return nextSync;
    }
    set {
        nextSync = value;
    }
}
```

How you can see the default value of `nextSync` is `N/A`, I can change the value of the variable from any classes.
At this point I've imported the control in my MainWindow in this way:

```
xmlns:OwnControl="clr-namespace:SynchronizationTool"
```

and use it as:

```
<OwnControl:Scheduler x:Name="Scheduler"/>
```

in the MainWindow class when I press the save button I want display a new value in the label, so:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Scheduler.NextSynchronization = "test";
}
```

the label should bind automatically the value `test`, but unfortunately, the label is still empty. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've created a `Test` class inside my control:

```
public class Test {
    private string nextSync = "N/A";

    public string NextSynchronization {
        get {
            return nextSync;
        }
        set {
            nextSync = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and in the `MainWindow` I use this:

```
DataContext = new CScheduler.Test();
```

seems that Label is initialized correctly with `N/A`

Comment: It has been a wile since i've used wpf so I'm not sure if this is still the required practice, but usually for a viewmodel to notify the view of changes it had to inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Is that still the case?

Comment: Have you set the `DataContext` correctly in your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` ?

Comment: @Nkosi yap that is still needed !

Comment: @FeDe Okay, my bad, seems that with a bit edit I can make it work, check my update

Comment: Then from his example I would say that his view model needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface so that the label is notified of the new value

Comment: @Nkosi there are some tutorial that I can learn?

Comment: Your main problem here was that there was no `DataContext` set. It even worked without `INotifyPropertyChanged` since it is only applying the value `N/A` when starting. So the first request on the Property is always working. When changig the value more often `INotifyPropertyChanged` is needed for sure !

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx Is a good point to start !

Comment: @FeDe Thanks, now seems working fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of setting the DataContext correctly:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplication.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"></CheckBox>
    <Button Content="{Binding BtnText}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //MainWindow.xaml.cs
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Create a new Instance of your ViewModel
        MyViewModelClass viewModel = new MyViewModelClass();
        //Set the DataContext (BindingContext (i.e. where to look for the Bindings) to your ViewModel
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Defining your ViewModelClass:

```
public class MyViewModelClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Add Constructor
    public MyViewModelClass()
    {

    }


    private string _text = "sampleText shown in the TextBox";

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set 
        {
            nextSync = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();//PropertyName will be passed automatically
        }
    }

    private string _isChecked = true;//CheckBox is checked by default

    public string IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked ; }
        set 
        {
            nextSync = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();//PropertyName will be passed automatically
        }
    }

    private string _btnText = "Click Me";//Text to display on the button

    public string BtnText
    {
        get { return _btnText ; }
        set 
        {
            nextSync = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();//PropertyName will be passed automatically
        }
    }



    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //When using the [CallerMemberName] Attribute you dont need to pass the PropertyName to the method which is pretty nice :D
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

Basically the `DataContext` tells the UI where to look for the Binding.
If this is not set, there will be binding errors shown in the output window in VisualStuido while building.

**UPDATE:**

If using `UserControls`:

Add a folder to your project called UserControls where you put the xamls.
Add a Namespace for them in your Window:

```
xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:<YourApplicationName>.UserControls"
```

Then add the `UserControl` to the Grid of your MainWindow:

```
<userControls:MyUserControl1></userControls:MyUserControl1>
```

Here comes the important part:

- If you DONT set the DataContext for the UserControl in UserControl.xaml.cs
  it will automatically use the one from the parent Control (which in your case           is the Window)
- So all the bindings you got in either window or usercontrols put in that 1 ViewModel
- Only set the `DataContext` for the Window.
- Now all the bindings should be taken from that viewmodel.

Comment: `MyViewModelClass` should contains all the method for each controls? I think that I'll create an interface or something like for inherit it in differents controls. If I've multiple classes how can I tell to DataContext to implement multiple MyViewModelClass?

Comment: Every Window gets a ViewModel. All the controls in one window have theire bindings in the same ViewModel

Comment: Ok, but suppose that I've two different controls (separate classes), MainWindow implement it, so I need to declare: `new MyViewModelClass1();` and `new MyViewModelClass2();`, so I've two instances of differents controls, how can I put this in one DataContext?

Comment: First how many Windows do you have ? (Count of XAML - Files) ? 
The count of XAML's has to be the same as the one of ViewModels

Comment: 1 window that import actually two controls (UserControl.xaml) files

Comment: I will update my answer give me a sec ... To much for comments

Comment: Hey just a thing: How can I access to DataContext from MainWindow method?

Comment: @Dillinger as `DataContext` is a Window Property you can only access it in the XAML or the xaml.cs file :D

Comment: please could you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320382/cant-update-ui-from-viewmodel-in-another-classes

Answer (score 2):

It is just a comment. First you should put a breakpoint on this line:

```
return nextSync;
```

But my main wondering is why you don't have any OnPropertyChanged after your "set" (your class implements INotifyPropertyChanged?):

```
public string NextSynchronization
{
    get
    {
        return nextSync;
    }
    set
    {
        nextSync = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("NextSynchronization");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: this sound's great! But what are the benefits of `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` tells the UI that the `Value` of a `Property` has changed and that the UI needs to update that property. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx for details

Comment: Basically: INotifyPropertyChanged help you to notify the client: basically UI will know that a new value was put into the binded property. So UI is able to actualize itself (in calling the get).

Comment: I improved the declaration as follows: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));` I guess that I should integrate this method in another class that allow me to inherit from other controls, right? @FeDe

Comment: @Benoît when I did: `DataContext = Scheduler.NextSynchronization = "Test";` the label doesn't update the value, and also is still empty, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Dillinger just have a look at MVVM and the link I posted as comment to your question. There it is described. Basically you have Views (XAML) and ViewModels (Classes (DataContext)). Every ViewModel has to Inherit from it. There is not really a need to improve or change sth. :D