# Can't update UI from ViewModel in another classes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've created an application that need a lot of access to UI controls, now what I did firstly is create an interface scalable, in particular I created different controls as `UserControl` and one class `ViewModel` that manage all method of this control for update the UI. Actually all working good in the `Main` thread. In particular the followin scenario working perfect:

**MainWindow XAML**

```
xmlns:MyControls="clr-namespace:HeavyAPP"
...
<!-- I use the control in the following way: -->
<Grid>
     <MyControls:Scheduler x:Name="Sc"/>
</Grid>
```

so for example the `Scheduler` control contains this `Data Binding`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Label x:Name="NextSync" Content="{Binding NextSynchronization, IsAsync=True}" ></Label>
</StackPanel>
```

**ViewModel structure**

```
public class ViewModelClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CScheduler scheduler;

    public ViewModelClass()
    {
        scheduler = new Scheduler();
    }

    public string NextSynchronization
    {
        get
        {
            return scheduler.GetNextSync();
        }
    }
}
```

How you can see in the `ViewModel` I've an instance of the `Scheduler` control and a `property` called `NextSyncrhonization` as the `binding`, so this property return a result from the method of the control instance.

For use this in the `MainWindow` I did the following:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    ViewModelClass viewModel = new ViewModelClass();
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

this automatically fill the control property. Now the problem's that I use a `BackgroundWorker` for perform some task, what I need is use the `DataContext` of `MainWindow` from different classes, (not Window, but classes).

For solve this situation I though to do something like this:

```
 MainWindow.AppWindow.Sc.SyncLog.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            new Action(() =>
            {
                ViewModelClass viewModel = new ViewModelClass();
                var dataContext = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext;
                dataContext = viewModel;
                viewModel.SynchronizationLog = "this is a test from other thread"}));
```

now `SynchronizationLog` is another property that append the text to the Control, just for precision, is this:

```
private string _text;
public string SynchronizationLog
{
        get
        {
            return _text += _text;
        }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
 }
```

this is the implementation of **INotifyPropertyChanged:**

```
`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
 {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 }`
```

this working only in the `MainWindow`, but in the external classes I can't update the UI, what am I doing wrong?

I reiceve no error, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

extend your ViewModel as follow:

```
public class ViewModelClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CScheduler scheduler;
    //Add this:
    public static ViewModelClass Instance {get; set;} //NEW
    public ViewModelClass()
    {
        scheduler = new Scheduler();
    }

    public string NextSynchronization
    {
        get
        {
            return scheduler.GetNextSync();
        }
    }
}
```

This changes your code in the xaml.cs to:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   ViewModelClass.Instance = new ViewModelClass();
   DataContext = viewModel.Instance;
}
```

In your external code you then DONT create a new Instance of the `ViewModelClass` - instead you use the existing one:

```
[...].Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if(ViewModelClass.Instance != null)
            {
               //Why you need the "var datacontext" in your example here ?
               ViewModelClass.Instance.SynchronizationLog = "this is a test from other thread"
            }
         }));
```

Basically what you do here is setting a property in your ViewModel from outside of your viewModel. This can be done from everywhere.

**What is different to your approach:**

1. We dont create a new Instance of the ViewModel (different bindings in the UI aren't resetted anymore)
2. We created an `Instance` so there can always be ONLY ONE viewModel at a time

Comment: Sounds good but there is a problem here: `ViewModelClass.Instance = new ViewModelClass();` you use `viewModel` variable but isn't declared

Comment: use the ClassName instead as this is a static property it should work => `ViewModelClass.Instance`

Comment: ClassName? What do you mean?

Comment: I don't know if this working, I'm stuck to this: `DataContext = viewModel.Instance;` where should I get this variable?

Comment: Dont use the variable use the `Class` itself same as when you use `ViewModelClass variable = new ViewModelClass();` Use `ViewModelClass.Insance` in that case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112391/discussion-between-dillinger-and-fe-de).